# Checkbox button works only first time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

i have an iphonestyle checkbox button made with a gem (ios-checkboxes) . I want through this button to show only some table rows(the completed/not completed specifications), depending on the button state. If i press it first time, works correct, after that it stops working.

Here is the view code.

```
= 'Show completed specifications'
= check_box @specifications, :status_set
%br
%table(id = "specifications")
  %thead
    %tr
      %th Title
      %th Added
      %th
  %tbody
    - @specifications.each do |spec|
      - if spec.status
        %tr{class: "completed"} // here i add a class on the COMPLETED specifications
          %th= spec.title
          %th= spec.created_at.strftime("%d-%m-%y %H:%M")
          %th= link_to "View", project_specification_path(params[:project_id], spec.id)
      - else
        %tr{class: "not_completed"} // NOT COMPLETED specifications
          %th= spec.title
          %th= spec.created_at.strftime("%d-%m-%y %H:%M")
          %th= link_to "View", project_specification_path(params[:project_id], spec.id)
```

the coffeescript code

```
$('.iPhoneCheckContainer').live "click", -> // the checkbox class
  is_completed = @.checked
  if is_completed
    $('.completed').show()
    $('.not_completed').hide()
  else
    $('.completed').hide()
    $('.not_completed').show()
```

Comment: Actually, the problem is that is_completed is not defined . Looks like the gem https://github.com/dnagir/ios-checkboxes doesn't recognize the .checked selector . How can i find if this button is checked or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with

```
is_completed = @.checked
```

Looks like the ios-checkboxes gem doesn t work like a normal checkbox.

I resolve the problem by adding a new class on the button with a function that switches a variable between true/false on any click event. Depending on that variable I displayed the completed/not completed specifications.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect what you really need to do is:

```
if $(this).is(':checked')
  // Stuff when checked
else
  // stuff when not checked
```

That would probably be the ideal way to check a normal checkbox.  Although I'm not sure what kind of markup ios-checkboxes generates so this may or may not work for you.

EDIT:

The `live` method is deprecated in jquery.  You should be using [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to bind events instead of `bind` or `live`:

```
$('.iPhoneCheckContainer').on "click", ->
  // Event
```

Comment: Actually, it doesn t act like a normal checkbox. I will try this way too . Thanks